# Use a sharepoint location as common repository to store visual studio project like TFS/Azure DevOps

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, tfs, azure-devops

I am given a sharepoint location from my organization. I have to save my Visual Studio project onto this location and use it as a repository/TFS/AzureDevOps like integration where my team members can access the project, map them to their space and work on the project.

Please help on this

Comment: **Do not do this**. Sharepoint is okay for document revision but is an awful solution for version control of code. Use real version control software.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Daniel Mann. SharePoint is used to share and manage content, knowledge, and applications to empower teamwork, quickly find information, and seamlessly collaborate across the organization. SharePoint isn't designed to be a source control tool for code. Based on my knowledge, it won't integrate with any IDEs, and it does not have customized GUI to manage source control code, etc.

There are many version control tools, like [Azure DevOps Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/), which can host unlimited free private repos and start free.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful? Is your issue solved?